# jquery live context

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, live

I'd like to do a live function on a selector, but i want to add a context depending on this selector.
I know that's wrong but what could be correct to make that right:

```
$('.myClass',$(this).parent()).live('myEvent',function(){..})
```

`.myClass` is a duplicated element class. And this 'live' make me possible to limit the event only in the context, in fact selector parent.
I hope I'm understandable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're looking for is the `.delegate()` function, which is just like `.live()`, but allows for a context (sort of), along [with other benefits](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/).

Try this code:

```
$(this).parent().delegate('.myClass','myEvent',function() { .. } );
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'd like to 'reduce' context the closest element to find others elements..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand you. My code above is a direct translation of what your code above is, but mine effectively limits the context to only the `parent`. `.live()` will **always** bind to the `document` context, no matter what your selector is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on(".myClass","event",function(){
   var select = $(this).parent();
   //use select for further implentation as selecter
})
```